# Bajo rendimiento al filtrar DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm, rendimiento

Hace tiempo estoy trabajando en WPF (MVVM), y hoy me encuentro con un problema que ya hace días no logro resolver.

La problemática es simple, tengo una ventana, donde debo mostrar una tabla con información (elegí `DataGrid` para hacerlo) y filtrarla con un `TextBox`

El problema, es que al tipear en el `TextBox` el rendimiento visual es **pésimo**, aveces al presionar una tecla, toma `0,3`, hasta `0,5` segundos en refrescar el `DataGrid`.

Aclaro que los registros a mostrar son muy pocos (130 aproximadamente)

Para llegar a lo que tengo, hice lo siguiente

Mi ViewModel

```
public class BuscarCatalogoViewModel : BaseViewModel<BuscarCatalogoViewModel>
{
    public ICollectionView ListaDeCatalogos { get; set; }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel> mListaPrivada;
    public ICommand SeleccionarCatalogoCommand { get; }
    public ICommand AbrirCatalogoCommand { get; }
    private string mFiltro;
    public string Filtro 
    {
        get => mFiltro;
        set {
            mFiltro = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(x => x.Filtro);
            Filtrar();
        }
    }
    private void Filtrar()
    {
        ListaDeCatalogos.Filter = o =>
        {            
            var obj = (BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel) o;            
            return
                obj.Titulo.Contains(Filtro, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || obj.Marca.Contains(Filtro, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || obj.Modelo.Contains(Filtro, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || obj.Codigo.Contains(Filtro, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        };
    }   

    public BuscarCatalogoViewModel
    {
        var catalogos = // Obtengo desde el repositorio y mapeo a un List<BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel> 
        mListaPrivada = new ObservableCollection<BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel>(catalogos);
        ListaDeCatalogos = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mListaPrivada);
    }
}
```

También la clase `BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel` que es el tipo de los items que muestro en el `DataGrid`

```
public class BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel : BaseViewModel<BuscarCatalogoItemViewModel>
{
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; } 
    public string Codigo => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath);
}
```

Por último, dentro de la vista, bindeo `ListaDeCatalogos` de la siguiente manera

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListaDeCatalogos}"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          AlternationCount="2"
          AlternatingRowBackground="#E7FFDE"
          >

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Path=Titulo}" Width="3*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marca" Binding="{Binding Path=Marca}" Width="2*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modelo" Binding="{Binding Path=Modelo}" Width="2*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command=
                            "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AbrirArchivoCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Style="{StaticResource BotonSinHover}" Margin="1">
                        <Button.ToolTip>Visualizar archivo</Button.ToolTip>
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Eye" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Foreground="DarkBlue"
                                         Height="18"
                                         Width="18"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command=
                            "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.SeleccionarCatalogoCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Style="{StaticResource BotonSinHover}" Margin="1">
                        <Button.ToolTip>¡Elegir accesorio!</Button.ToolTip>
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="CheckCircle" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         Foreground="Green"
                                         Height="18"
                                         Width="18"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

¿Por qué estoy teniendo este problema de rendimiento?

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Buscando en SOen, encontré mucha información relacionada a estos problemas de rendimiento donde la solución han sido temas relacionados a la virtualización, cosa que en mi caso no ha funcionado.

Desde ya gracias!

Comment: Me explicas el recorrido de tu codigo desde que presionas una letra en el textbox hasta que pasa algo?

Comment: @gbianchi Al presionar una tecla en el `TextBox`, se ejecuta el Setter de la propiedad `Filtro` (por lo que se guarda en la variable privada) y después ejecuto el método `Filtrar()` que es el que modifica el predicado del filtro de `ICollectionView`, al finalizar ese método, ya se refrescó la UI

Comment: Pero eso lo esta haciendo por cada letra... no es como mucho por cada letra? no deberias esperar a filtrar hasta tener algo mas concreto?

Comment: @gbianchi lo hice por cada letra por un tema de practicidad, puedo perfectamente poner un botón y esperar el click para filtrarlo, lo que me extrañó es que le cueste tanto trabajo filtrar 130 registros, de ahí nace la pregunta :P

Comment: No debe ser un problema de vista.. pero habria que hacer un profiling de cada cosa a ver donde esta el tema...

Comment: Intenta crear un Command para el evento del textbox en vez de la propiedad filtro, adicionalmente, recuerdo hace mucho haber hecho algo similar colocando un conteo minimo de letras y un pequeño tiempo de espera en milisegundos despues de la ultima tecla para recién buscar.
También se mejora lo visual si usas métodos asíncronos, ya que no bloquean